# Executor is taking more memory than defined

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

```
spark-submit --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 5g --master yarn --executor-cores 3 --class com.octro.hbase.hbase_final /home/hadoop/testDir/nikunj/Hbase_data_maker/target/Hbase_data_maker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar main_user_profile
```

This is my command to execute my spark code on the cluster.
On this command my **YARN** page gives total memory allocated as

```
71GB
```

I tried searching on the internet for the various reason but didn't received any clear clarification.
Later I figured out it is using the formula as

```
No of Executors*(Memory*2)+1
```

Plus 1 is for the main container.But why that `2GB` by default.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of 2GB memory overhead that was specified in configuration file of spark.
That's why it was taking 2GB more.